# Can't set constraints for duplicated views (Xcode 11.0)

Tags: ios, xcode

After updating Xcode to 11.0, I am having an issue where I cannot set constraints for a duplicated view in the Storyboard.  Xcode is forcing me to recreate a new view from scratch in order to set the constraints on it.

I was not having this issue before updating Xcode.  Has anyone else experienced this and found a way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nevermind I just solved it.. turns out when I duplicate a view now, it sets the "Layout" to "Translates Mask into Constraints" and I have to set it back to "Automatic".  It wasn't doing this for me prior to the update.